# When is Bayesian Inference, more helpful than naive frequentist updating over a stream?

Tags: bayesian

When is Bayesian Inference more helpful than naive updating by prior evidence, for a prediction task over a stream?

Imagine a stream of data accumulating over time. And there are no a-priori assumed parameters which experts attribute very high certainty to (maybe only some assumptions here and there, which are more intuitive than *believed* by experts). A humble amount of evidence has accumulated already, not large enough for other kinds of machine learning. Why is it then not efficient/helpful/sensible to directly assume the so-far observed probability, in its frequentist sense, and thereafter repeat this naive update ongoing or on interval, rather than using Bayesian inference?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you're getting at here, but you may be interested in checking out [empirical Bayesian methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method). Note that within the Frequentist paradigm, [meta-analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis) serves a similar function of combining multiple sources of information.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason not to proceed in a Bayesian way for this problem. Starting with a reference prior on the unknown parameter, $\theta$, the posterior distribution on $\theta$ gets updated after each new observation and so does the predictive distribution $p(x_{n+1}|x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. If the model is regular enough, the posterior and the predictive concentrate at the same speed as the MLE, enjoys a Central Limit (Bernstein-von Mises) theorem, &tc. while providing for a finite $n$ a complete array of inferential answers.

In addition, highly efficient computational tools like particle filters have been devised exactly for this kind of problems and hence deliver Monte Carlo approximations to the sequence of posterior at a limited computational cost.

Comment: Although I have upvoted the anwer, it doesn't directly touch at the core of the question asked ― which if paraphrased is ― what is the advantage of using Bayesian Inference over the stream. In layman terms I find that it "evens out" the error compared to assuming the frequentist observation, potentially providing a reasonable way of accounting for uncertainty as it would in the non-streaming case. Which applies only if "good" initial priors where chosen and the more the chosen distribution is relevant to the phenomenon being modeled.